# How to compare structs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, struct

I have an issue with PowerShell. I work with a legacy application and they use structs. I would like to use something else, but that would require an enormous amount of work since the struct is EVERYWHERE in the code base.

The issue is that I have an array with ALOT of structs. The structs contain two string, lets call them stringA and stringB. Only stringA should determine if two structs are equal to each other. I would like to remove the duplicates. Usually I do this by throwing objects into a HashSet or by doing something like in the code example. How do I do this with a struct? I would like to compare ONLY stringA.

```
# This is how I retrieve the array
[myStruct[]]$myArray = SomeMethodThatGivesMeAnArray

# The way I remove duplicates when working with string arrays.
$myArray = $myArray | Select -Uniq

# The struct 
add-type @"
public struct myStruct {
    public string stringA;
    public string stringB;
}
"@
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Adding a method like the one below doesn't help at all. It isn't called when I use Select -Uniq

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (stringA ?? String.Empty).GetHashCode();
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the code similar to your string array duplicate remover.  You would use the `Sort-Object` cmdlet with the `-Unique` and `-Property` parameters:

```
$uniqueArray = $myArray | Sort-Object -Unique -Property StringA
```

This does add some overhead in terms of the cost of sorting the array, but it will return an array of your structs consisting of unique values of `stringA`.  Be warned that for a given value of `myStruct.stringA`, this will return the struct that is the first encountered in the original array.

Give it a try

```
[Namespace.myStruct[]]$myArray = @([Namespace.myStruct]@{stringA="a";stringB="b"},[Namespace.myStruct]@{stringA="a";stringB="FFF"},[Namespace.myStruct]@{stringA="b";stringB="b"},[Namespace.myStruct]@{stringA="b";stringB="Other String"})
$uniqueArray = $myArray | Sort-Object -Unique -Property StringA
```

`$myArray` will hold:

```
stringA  stringB                                                                                   
-------  -------                                                                                   
a        b                                                                                         
a        FFF                                                                                       
b        b                                                                                         
b        Other String
```

`$uniqueArray` will hold:

```
stringA stringB
------- -------
a       b      
b       b
```